# how to use tsfresh python package to extract features from time series data?

Tags: python, time-series, feature-extraction, tsfresh

I have a list of lists where each list represents a time series :

```
tsli=[[43,65,23,765,233,455,7,32,57,78,4,32],[34,32,565,87,23,86,32,56,32,57,78,32],[87,43,12,46,32,46,13,23,6,90,67,8],[1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,9],[12,34,56,76,34,12,45,67,34,21,12,22]]
```

i want to extract feature from this dataset with tsfresh package using code:

```
import tsfresh
tf=tsfresh.extract_features(tsli)
```

When i'm running it i'm getting Value error which is:

```
> ValueError: You have to set the column_id which contains the ids of the different time series
But i don't know how to deal with this and how to define column id for this problem.
```

**EDIT 1:**
As suggested i had tried by converting the dataset into data and then tried :

```
import tsfresh
df=pd.DataFrame(tsli)
tf=tsfresh.extract_features(df)
```

but the Value error is same

```
> ValueError: You have to set the column_id which contains the ids of the different time series
```

Any resource or reference will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Tsfresh seem to use dataframes as Data Formats, not list.

Comment: so even if i convert it to df then also how to set column id for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you have to convert your `list` to a `dataframe`, where every time-series has an unique id, e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i, ts in enumerate(tsli):
    data = [[x, i] for x in ts]
    df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
df.columns = ['value', 'id']
```

[image] ... [image]

Now you can use tsfresh with `column_id` argument on the created column:

```
tf=tsfresh.extract_features(df, column_id='id')


>> Feature Extraction: 100%|██████████| 5/5 [00:00<00:00, 36.83it/s]
```

Another example: [tsfresh Quick Start](https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/text/quick_start.html)

Comment: I have a confusion, why we have index from 0 to 59 ,is it taking all timeseries as single time series? And thanks for the solution.

Comment: You are welcome :-) Yes,  tsfresh needs all the time-series to be "stacked up as a single time series" and separated by an id (therefore the column). That is because if you want to do multivariate time-series analysis you can still use a Matrix / 2D-dataframe. You can ignore the index btw.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot :)